# Why does my string doesn't get modified to one of the values present in the dictionary in Python after length of string becomes equal to key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, while-loop

I have a number 'n' (n=60, for example), my task is to convert the number into string empty = 'sixzero' and calculate the length of string and further modify it in following way, ***length of 'sixzero' is 7 so further modification of the string is 'seven', the length of seven is 5 , so further it will be modified to 'five' and then length will be 4 so it will be modified to 'four' and at this point it should stop because length of string will be 4 and value of string is also 'four'. I need to return 'four'*** , so Initially I achieved empty = 'sixzero' but I am not able to achieve the final result 'four'. Below is my code.

```
 class Solution(object):

    # (60)

   def numbers_of_letters(self,n):

       arr = {0:'zero',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',
              6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine'}
       empty = ''
       modi =''

       to_char_array = list(map(int, str(n)))
       for i in range(len(to_char_array)):

            if to_char_array[i] in arr.keys():
                 empty += str(arr.get(to_char_array[i]))
            else:
                 pass
            k=0
            while len(empty) not in arr.values():
                if len(empty) in arr.keys():
                 modi += str(arr.get(k))
                else:
                    pass
       return modi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=60
    print(Solution().numbers_of_letters(n))
```

Comment: What happens when first step returns two digit number? (e.g. 88 -> eighteight -> 10)?

Comment: len(ten) is 3 ,so it will be modified to three -> five -> four and output will be four

Comment: Okay but where does "ten" come from?

Comment: Shouldn't it become "onezero" instead?

Comment: len(eighteight) is 10 ,so it should give 'ten'. My code is correct until 'eighteight'

Comment: `arr` doesn't contain mapping for 10.

Comment: nope, it doesn't become 'onezero' , you have caluclate string length only after once inital number is converted to a string.

Comment: If your inital input is 10 then it will return 'onezero' but then you just have to keep counting length of the string and return value from dictionary for the length you got (that length would be key in dictionary), you have to keep doing this until your length and value aren't same

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. How is the code supposed to know that `10` is `"ten"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251010/discussion-between-aurora19-and-matszwecja).

Comment: Where is your test such that when you do achieve the string `"four"` that you realise the length of that is `4` which was the number you converted through your `arr`?

Comment: That is the code that I am going wrong

Comment: What code do you propose to write that performs the test I think you need?

Comment: Do you realise that whatever value you pass for *n* the (correct) result will always be 'four'?

Comment: @Fred: Oh, that means `return 'four'` is a valid solution.

Comment: Yes 'four' is the valid solution

Comment: @quamrana My statement that the result will always be 'four' is a comment - not a solution. I have provided a solution

Comment: You could also have written: `def number_of_letters(n): return 'four'`?

Comment: @Fred: I mean I'm dumb and didn't realise that the answer will always be 'four'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial recursive approach will give you the answer you need. Note that whatever value is passed to this function, the result will **always** be 'four'

```
MAP = [
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
    'six',
    'seven',
    'eight',
    'nine'
]

def as_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return MAP[0]
    s = []
    while n > 0:
        s.append(MAP[n%10])
        n //= 10
    return ''.join(s)

def number_of_letters(n):
    s = as_string(n)
    if (ls := len(s)) == n:
        return s
    return number_of_letters(ls)

print(number_of_letters(60))
```

**Output:**

```
four
```

**Note:**

The as_string() function will return the string, effectively, in reverse. For example, for a value of 60 it would return 'zerosix'. However, that doesn't matter because we're only concerned with the return value's length.

The integer arithmetic in the as_string() function performs significantly better than any solution involving conversion to and from str <-> int

**Alternative:**

Using same MAP list:

```
def as_string(n):
    def _next(n):
        if n == 0:
            yield 0
        while n > 0:
            yield n % 10
            n //= 10
    return ''.join(reversed([MAP[i] for i in _next(n)]))


def number_of_letters(n, rv=None):
    if rv is None:
        rv = list()
    rv.append(s := as_string(n))
    if (ls := len(s)) == n:
        return rv
    return number_of_letters(ls, rv)

print(number_of_letters(60))
```

**Output:**

```
['sixzero', 'seven', 'five', 'four']
```

Comment: What if I have to return array as an input? for example for input n=12 , I want to return arr = ["onetwo", "six", "three", "five", "four"]

Comment: @Aurora19 To do that you would have to modify the code

Comment: Ahh, yes.. found the way to do it, I created an empty array res and in while res[-1]!='four: res.append(modified)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach, using two helper functions for each step:

```
class Solution(object):
    def numbers_of_letters(self,n):
        while True:
            new_n = words_to_number(number_to_words(n))
            if new_n == n:
                break
            else:
                n = new_n
        return number_to_words(new_n)


def words_to_number(words):
    print("".join(words))
    return sum(map(len, words))

def number_to_words(n):
    print(n)
    arr = {0:'zero',1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',
              6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine'}
    to_char_array = list(map(int, str(n)))
    words = list(map(lambda x: arr[x], to_char_array))
    return words

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=60
    print(Solution().numbers_of_letters(n))
```

Comment: What if I have to return array as an input? for example for input n=12 , I want to return arr = ["onetwo", "six", "three", "five", "four"]

Comment: You can assign return value of number_to_words to a variable, append it to some list, and proceed with words_to_number.

Comment: something like this while result[-1]!='four' , result.append(modified) ?

Answer (score 0):

So an answer in the style of the OP just loops round while the end condition is not true:

```py
class Solution:
    
    def numbers_of_letters(self, n):
        arr = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']

        while True:
           number_as_str = str(n)
           text = ''
           for digit in number_as_str:
               text += arr[int(digit)]
           if len(text) == n:
               return text
           n = len(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n=463829
    print(Solution().numbers_of_letters(n))
```

Output:

`four`

And as @Fred pointed out the trivial version is:

```py
class Solution:
    def numbers_of_letters(self, n):
        return 'four'
```

Comment: can we store every modification in a list and show it as output?

Comment: Yes, but you seem to be asking a new question. You should do that.